# Which one is faster? Swift’s .filter or NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Which is faster for filtering an array? Swift’s `.filter` or using NSPredicate? I just wanted to know which is faster so I can proceed using the faster one. (Please elaborate why it is faster than the other.)

Answer (score 4):

What are you filtering? How many records? What kinds of predicates? Are the tests dynamic or static? Is all the data in memory or are you filtering across Core Data or something else? Are you filtering an array or a generic Sequence? How is that Sequence generated (does it all exist in memory at the same time)? Is your Sequence a Collection that can accessed in parallel or is it a sequentially generated Sequence? What do you do with the data afterwards that might be optimized further? What have your preliminary tests suggested? Is there a particular reason to limit yourself to these two choices (there are several other approaches)? And given that Swift's performance characteristics will likely dramatically change over the coming year as the optimizer improves, how important is it that this answer be valid three months from now?

As @zoul suggests, use the one that is more readable for your problem, and then tune if there is an issue.

If you still have no idea, use `filter`. It is strictly typed, which typically makes it a better solution for writing in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

Given the way you ask, it does not matter. Choose the one that reads better. (And if you really really want to know, profile your use case.)